# No connection type provided, no 'x-type' property defined

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to connect to my hyperledger network through nodejs sdk 
`bizNetworkConnection.connect("card_name")` and it throws

```
Error: No connection type provided, probably because the connection profile has
no 'x-type' property defined.
```

I am using composer rest api to interact, but then got to know that they don't support loopback filters except "where". So now i am trying to connect through node sdk. Network is up and running no errors in network. composer version 0.16.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your application is using the composer sdk libraries newer than 0.16.x. A connection profile with an `x-type` property was introduced into version 0.17 and higher and the fact you get this error means you must be using a later version. For your application you should fix your dependencies on `composer-client`, `composer-admin` to 0.16.3, for example

```
"dependencies" : {
    "composer-client" : "0.16.3",
    "composer-admin" : "0.16.3"
}
```

Comment: Before i had tried composer-client 0.17.0, 0.16.0, but didn't try 0.16.3.
Now i tried 0.16.3 and it works, Thanks